# How to replace multiple characters instead of using replace n times

Tags: javascript

i want to replace "()," to whitespaces in a string now i can do it with 3times of

```
str=str.replace('(',' ');
str=str.replace(')',' ');
str=str.replace(',',' ');
```

I read about regex, to make it easier but my trie with

```
str=str.replace(/(),/,' ');
```

failed.

What i do wrong?

Comment: You need to use regex alternation and correctly escape brackets: `/\(|\)|,/`

Comment: Do you want to replace any occurrence of those chars or the specific string `(),`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You need add the characters you want to replace to a [character class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets):

```js
let str = "(this is a string with commas,,)"
str = str.replace(/[(),]/g, ' ')
console.log(str)
```

Comment: For extended info and examples about the character class check out the [regular-expression.info coverage](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: There's no mention of the `g` modifier, which is the answer to the question "instead of using replace n times". Even though the code is correct, this answer fails to answer the original question.

Answer (score 2):

- Use the global flag `g` after the regex.
- `(` and `)` are special characters, so they need escaping.
- Use `|` operator to match any of the strings found
- If you are only searching for characters you could a character class instead, like: `[(),]`

Example matching whole string:

```js
function fixString(text){
 return text.replace(/\(|\)|,/g, " ");
}

console.log(fixString(",1)2(3"));
```

Example matching characters:

```js
function fixString(text){
 return text.replace(/[(),]/g, " ");
}

console.log(fixString(",1)2(3"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`(` and `)` have a special meaning in RegEx. Place them in square brackets. You also have to specify the global [`g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) flag to replace for the multiple occurrences.

```js
var str='test(),test2';

str=str.replace(/[(),]/g, ' ');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a character class with a global flag to replace.

```
/[(),]/g
```

```js
function fixString(text){
   return text.replace(/[(),]/g, " ");
}

console.log(fixString(",1)2(3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this regex - `/[(,)]/g`. See it live below -

```js
var x1 = '34(,12';
var x2 = '34),12';
var x3 = '34()12';
var x4 = '34,12';
var x5 = ',1)2(3';

x1 = x1.replace(/[(,)]/g, ' ');
x2 = x2.replace(/[(,)]/g, ' ');
x3 = x3.replace(/[(,)]/g, ' ');
x4 = x4.replace(/[(,)]/g, ' ');
x5 = x5.replace(/[(,)]/g, ' ');

console.log(x1);
console.log(x2);
console.log(x3);
console.log(x4);
console.log(x5);
```

**Suggestion:** You could isolate it using a generic function as follows -

```js
var filterString = (str) => str.replace(/[(,)]/g, ' ');

var x = '3,4,5(6,7),1)2(3';

console.log(filterString(x));
```